# How to handle switching between onClick events of menu items ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The question i have is a bit difficult to explain so please bear with me,
I have implemented actionBar for an app, the thing is i have 5-6 menu items on the actionBar and handling the click event using

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

what happens is each menu item click inflates a particular view in a common region[i.e the inflated views overlap each other,not a common container],
i need to remove that view and inflate another one if another item is clicked,and i achieve this using simple if comparison statements.

While the solution is simple,implementing it and checking for so many conditions makes it complex and the code unreadable.

I just want to know if there exists a more elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference to the last inflated view:

```
private View lastInflatedView;
```

in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method hide the view with this reference and set it to the next inflated.

```
if (lastInflatedView != null) {
 lastInflatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

View newView = //inflate here
lastInflatedView = newView;
```

Comment: i am doing something similar,by keeping track of the last selected menu item, and using it. The approach is similar and still makes it complex to read. Moreover sorry for misleading,but its not exactly a common container,it is a area wgere the inflated views overlap each other

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume here you're using fragments for this 'common area', if you're not using you should start using. And the code is pretty simple (ps. I'm writing it from memory, so fix any lil mistakes I might have):

```
    onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_item_1:
                     // Instantiate the fragment for the item_1
                     Fragment frag = new ... etc.... etc
                     // note I'm using replace, so it will remove whatever was there before.
                    getFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.common_area, frag).commit();
                return true;
                case R.id.menu_item_2:  // repeat for all the menus

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
    }
```

Comment: i am using fragments,but the thing is its not a common area in that sense,i have edited my question,sorry for the ambiguous statement

Comment: sorry. I don't follow. Maybe if you post your layout.